# How to download excel file on ajax success

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, download

I am downloading excel file on client side using ajax. File is downloaded but in encrypted code. I have tried so far is as below:

Code on servlet side:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=ErrorDocument.xls");
System.out.println("session get : " + (request.getSession().getAttribute("errorFile") instanceof Workbook));

try {
    Workbook errorWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    errorWorkbook = (Workbook) request.getSession().getAttribute("errorFile");
    java.io.OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    errorWorkbook.write(out);
    out.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'errorFileDownload',
    method:'post',
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        console.log("In success of file download.");
        if(response!=""){
            // check for a filename
            var filename = "";
            var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
            if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
            }

            var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
            console.log("Content-type :" + type);
            var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });

            if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                if (filename) {
                    // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    // safari doesn't support this yet
                    if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                        window.location = downloadUrl;
                    } else {
                        a.href = downloadUrl;
                        a.download = filename;
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                    }
                } else {
                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                }

                setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // cleanup
            }
        } else {
            alert("file is not available");
        }
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("error occure here...");
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just redirect to the document, with the correct content-disposition set, that way it does the same thing as your ajax function, without any javascript at all ?

Comment: I also tried that but it was giving me only a blank page. So i go ahead with this.

Comment: @adeneo can you give me some hint how can i do it without ajax?

Comment: It should work out of the box, with the right content-disposition etc. If it's just giving you a blank page when you visit the url directly, how would you get something different with ajax? The issue is probably serverside.

Comment: @adeneo thank you for your suggestion. I have used simple anchor tag and call servlet and its working now.

Comment: try updating dataType: "text/csv" in your ajax call.